# New record does not get a generated id

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, postgresql-9.6

I created a new table which gets migrated via FlywayDB on startup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS place_address (
  id bigint,
  place_id bigint NOT NULL,
  street character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  postal_code character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  city character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  country character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  address_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES place(id),

  CONSTRAINT place_address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am creating such an entity and store it with a `JpaRepository`:

```
PlaceAddressEntity placeAddressEntity = new PlaceAddressEntity();
placeAddressEntity.setPlace(placeEntity);
placeAddressEntity.setStreet(establishmentDto.getAddress().getStreet());
placeAddressEntity.setCity(establishmentDto.getAddress().getCity());
placeAddressEntity.setCountry(establishmentDto.getAddress().getCountry());
placeAddressEntity.setPostalCode(establishmentDto.getAddress().getPostalCode());
placeAddressEntity.setAddressType(AddressType.GEOGRAPHIC);

this.placeAddessRepository.save(placeAddressEntity);
```

However, this is what I am getting:

```
2018-09-21 18:42:05.319  WARN 13842 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2018-09-21 18:42:05.319 ERROR 13842 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 8, Western Road 2-20, NW10 7LW, Greater London, United Kingdom, GEOGRAPHIC).
2018-09-21 18:42:05.322  INFO 13842 --- [io-8443-exec-10] m.a.s.e.CustomRestExceptionHandler       : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
2018-09-21 18:42:05.323  INFO 13842 --- [io-8443-exec-10] m.a.s.e.CustomRestExceptionHandler       : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

The entity is defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place_address")
public class PlaceAddressEntity {

    public enum AddressType {
        GEOGRAPHIC,
        BILLING
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "place_id", nullable = false)
    private PlaceEntity place;

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "address_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AddressType addressType;

}
```

I have no idea what the problem is - any idea what I am missing?

---

Here is also `PlaceAddressRepository`:

```
public interface PlaceAddessRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceAddressEntity, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not using auto incrementaion feature

use `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, it must be set in table definition.

Comment: I had to go with `BIGSERIAL` but that's essentially what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post an answer as I saw @Antoniossss answer. However, I post mine just so we can see what `SERIAL`, or in my case `BIGSERIAL` does for us.

I was able to make it work with this:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.place_address_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NO MINVALUE
  NO MAXVALUE
  CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.place_address_id_seq OWNED BY public.place_address.id;

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.place_address ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.place_address_id_seq'::regclass);
```

However, I kind of preferred this one liner:

```sql
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
```